# OpenMP parallel for not working as expected

Tags: for-loop, parallel-processing, openmp

I have simple program:

```
int index;
unsigned int count = 0;

#pragma omp parallel for
for (index = 0; index < 10000; index++)
{
    count++;
}
```

Problem is that I think count should be equal to 10000. But instead it is usually somewhere around 5000. In about 10% it is equal to 10000.

What is going on here?

Comment: `count++` is not an atomic operation

Comment: Thanks after added `#pragma omp atomic` it worked

Comment: But then, the performance of this loop drops down

Comment: Is there way to do this faster?

Comment: `count = 10000;` (a smart enough compiler will figure it out on its own), seriously, why do you want to parallelize this loop ?

Comment: This is just simplified snipped from my program

Comment: `count++` protected by `atomic` is one well-trodden path to writing serial programs with the overhead of OpenMP.  Don't follow that path.  Instead, learn how to use OpenMP's `reduction` variables.  You'll find enough to get you started by searching here on SO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As suggested in comments, you need [reduction](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/openMP/#REDUCTION) directive:

```
int index;
unsigned int count = 0;

#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:count)
for (index = 0; index < 10000; index++)
{
    count++;
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't say _need_ probably although this is a way to fix the issue.